# Category description not changing

Tags: magento

I have a category, for arguments sake lets call it Beans.

Beans has a title, and it has a description.

If I make a change to the title of Beans, it gets reflected on the front end fine.

If I make a change to the description of Beans, it does NOT get reflected on the front end. If I completely delete the description of Beans, I can still see the old description on the front end. No changes I make to the description comes thru to the front end what-so-ever.

I have all the cache's turned off.

I have cleared the cleared the caches from the Admin Panel.

I have manually deleted the contents of `/var/cache/`.

I have disabled and re-enabled the category.

I have disabled the category, deleted the contents of `/var/cache/`, cleared the caches from the Admin Panel, and then re-enabled the category.

The old description for the Beans category still shows, but any changes I make to the title is reflected fine each time.

How can I stop the description for the category Beans from being cached? Other categories are unaffected by this, only Beans seems to want to keep hold of its old description.

This is in Magento 1.9

Comment: Check if your category description is overwritten on another scope, e.g. Store View.

Comment: @GerarddeVisser it was over written in another scope - thanks for your help - add this as an answer and I will mark you as correct

Comment: Great to hear that your problem is solved. I added this as answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: please define "programming" - perhaps configuring Magento isnt programming, but then again neither is HTML or CSS and there is plenty of that here. Is XML considered to be programming? As much of Magento is configured with XML, and that could have been the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if your category description is overwritten on another scope, e.g. Store View.